# How to get Seq[String] instead of Seq[Any]?

Tags: scala, collections

I need to do the following transformation and `columnNames` should be `Seq[String]`, however it is always `Seq[Any]`.
How can I solve this task?

```
val cols = Seq("col1","col2")
val columnNames: Seq[String] = cols ++ "col3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do :

```
val columnNames: Seq[String] = cols :+ "col3"
```

or

```
val columnNames: Seq[String] = cols ++ Seq("col3")
```

In your case the result is `Seq[Any]` because `Any` is the common supertype of `String` and `Char`

Comment: rather "... because Any is a common supertype of `String` and `Char`"

Comment: Is there any way to EXCLUDE `col3` from Seq("col1","col2","col3") ?

Comment: @ScalaBoy please open a new question to ask that

Answer (score 1):

`++` is the binary operator(method) on two collections. But the `:+` or `+:` is the operator to add an `element` to the `collection`( the `collection` should always be adjacent to `:` and the `element` to be added to the collection should always be adjacent to `+` in `:+`  ie., it should be used as `collection :+ element` or `element +: collection` to `append` or `prepend` the `element` to the `collection` respectively.So, the `cols :+"col3"` will give us the expected answer, because then the `"col3"` will be treated as a `string element` to be added to `cols` `collection`.

While using, `cols ++ "col3"` , the `String` `"col3"` is being treated by the compiler as a collection ie.,as `List('c','o','l','3')`, `cols` is a collection of strings. Hence the resulting collection is `List[Any]`, because it contains strings and chars, the super-type of `String` and `Char` is inferred to be `Any` by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :
`val columnNames: Seq[String] = cols :+ "col3"`

`:+` is a method on whatever type is returned by someVariable.next().

You are getting Class `Any` is the root of the Scala class hierarchy. Every class in a Scala execution environment inherits directly or indirectly from this class.